# coredata sort by number of relationship

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

In Core Data when entities have one to many or many to many relationship, how do we sort based on number of relationship?

For example

I want to know mothers with the most children

How would I do so in objective-c

Answer (score 0):

This sort:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor 
   sortDescriptorWithKey:@"children.count"];
```

would work, but (assuming children is faulted) would use key-value coding methods on the children property, which in turn would fire the fault, so you'd lose the performance benefits of batching and faulting.

Another (debatable) approach is to keep the count as an attribute to the mother entity. You could then do a direct court without having to query the relationship at all.